# Binary files on c

Tags: c, file, binary

Trying to save an array of structs in a binary file.
I think i need a for.

```
typedef struct {
    int y, o;
}num;


int main(){
    num numbers[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        numbers [i].y = i;
        numbers [i].o = i * 2;
    }
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("test","r+");

}
```

Comment: What is your file format going to be?

Comment: you blow array bounds. you go to the the 11th index [10] but you only define 10

Comment: ok corrected.. still FILE PROBLEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if compatibility to different architectures and/or compilers isn't really of concern you can just write it like you would any data ( in a sense where you write is where you will load it). if you have to have compatiblity you can't use this method you will have to write functions to read and write on a more abstract level.

1. pass a reference to your data into the first `fwrite()`, in your case a pointer to numbers
2. use the `sizeof()` function on your struct name in the 2nd argument, this tells the function how big your data is. `sizeof(num)` for you
3. use the amount of indeces of the array to write the correct amount to file. you have 10 so `10`.
4. last is the `FILE *`

see here a short example:

```
typedef struct {
    int y, o;
}num;


int main(){
    num numbers[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   // you blow array bounds, fixed
        numbers [i].y = i;
        numbers [i].o = i * 2;
    }
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("test","r+");
    if (f != NULL) {
        fwrite(&numbers, sizeof(num), 10, f);
        fclose(f);    
    } else {
        // fopen error...
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run that code

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct {
          int y, o;
 }num;


 int main()
 {
    num numbers[10];
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            numbers [i].y = i;
            numbers [i].o = i * 2;
    }

    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("test","r+");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    fprintf(f," %d %d " ,numbers[i].y,numbers[i].o);      
 }
```